# Найти значение функции

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Простое задание - написать программу вычисления функции на C++. Исходные результаты: x=5, a = 3.3

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace::std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    double x, y;
    const double a = 3.3;
    cout << "Введите x: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    y = 12.7 * pow(asin(3 * pow(x, 2)), 3) / pow(log(sqrt(x + exp(a))), 2);
    cout << "y = " << y;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Результат справа (2,814), однако с моим исходником получается -nan(ind). Пытался и по модулю значения под корнем брать - никак. Что я пропустил?

Comment: арксинус(75) не существует, Ваш ответ - правильный

Comment: [вольфрам](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%2812.7+%28arcsin%283+x%5E2%29%29%5E3%29%2F%28ln%5E2%28sqrt%28x%2Bexp%283.3%29%29%29%29+%3D+2.814) подсказывает что `x=0.5`. Возможно в задании просто написано `.5` - без ведущего нуля?

Comment: Не вычисляйте целые степени через pow().

Comment: @Grundy: Отличный пример телепатии, подкреплённой современными техническими средствами. Опубликуйте как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, добавил, но что-то он не смотрится как-то :-)

Comment: @Grundy: По-моему, очень даже ничего.

Answer (score 2):

[*Wolfram*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%2812.7%20%28arcsin%283%20x%5E2%29%29%5E3%29%2F%28ln%5E2%28sqrt%28x%2Bexp%283.3%29%29%29%29%20%3D%202.814) показывает, что для указанных значений `a=3.3` и ответа 2.814 существует подходящее значение *x=0.5*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значит наиболее вероятно, что в задании число 0.5 было записано, без ведущего "0" - **.5**

Answer (score 0):

Функции `sin, asin, cos` и другие подобные им возвращают значения в радианах. 
Вы можете почитать об использовании этих функций [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txk32e70.aspx).
Если необходимо получать градусы, то нужно писать `asin(выражение)*180/PI`

Comment: Выше уже указывали на то, что `x=0.5`.